# qgis feature classification of filegdb datasource bug?

Tags: qgis, file-geodatabase

When I am trying to create a symbol classification from a filegdb datasource in qgis the list of unique attribute values is not being populated when I hit the 'Classify' button. It loads a single color block and and empty space for value.

If I convert this dataset to a .shp and try to classify it, it works as expected. This is happening when the datasource is loaded with both the openfilegdb driver and the ESRI Filegdb driver. Is this a bug?

after hitting 'classify' with the gdb:

[image]

after hitting classify on the .shp version:

[image]

I'm using qgis 2.14.0 on Mac OSX 10.11.4, GDAL 1.11.4

Comment: Certainly sounds like a bug. Please report it on the QGIS issue tracker and attach a file for reproducing the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade to 2.14.2. It's been fixed already.

Comment: Thanks for that info. I'll check this when the mac dmg for 2.14.2 gets finished and posted on the KyngChaos page.

Comment: 2.14.1 should also have the fix, if that helps

Comment: 2.14.2 does fix this issue.